# Usage of bare infinitive

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives, infinitive-clauses

> 1). Do you wish to watch TV or **to go** to bed early.
>
> 2). Do you wish to watch TV or **go** to bed early.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences? My friend is saying second sentence is correct because we should use bare infinitive after **or**. Is he correct?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning, but your friend is correct in saying that the second _to_ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate said, there is no difference in meaning between the two. Sentence #2 is an example of elision, where a word ("to") has been omitted because it is understood from the context.

Elision is common in tight prose, which might be subjectively better, but it is not more "correct". If memory serves, *Strunk and White* even has a section on this saying prepositions should be reinserted when it clarifies meaning, for example in a long series of phrases.